# apache2 https redirect to http without ssl cert

Tags: https, apache2

We have an apache server which hosts multiple domains from, which  some have https enabled and some do not.

Now the problem is that if I access https://exampleWithoutHttps I will come to the content of https://exampleWithHttps.

I would like to  forward the user from https://exampleWithoutHttps to http://exampleWithoutHttps on all domains whithout https. I have tried to create a redirect rule in virtualhost *:443 but this creates the following error:

Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured

The problem is that I cant change "Listen 443" to "Listen 443 http" as this would break my hosts with ssl enabled.

Is there a way I could have a redirect without a ssl certificate ?

Or if not possible  can you propose an alternative which would ensure that  https://exampleWithoutHttps does not show the content of   https://exampleWithHttps.

My ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
```

mi site condfig:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /path/to/dr
 ServerName  exampleWithoutHttps.com
 ServerAlias www.exampleWithoutHttps.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName  exampleWithoutHttps.com
 ServerAlias www.exampleWithoutHttps.com
 Redirect permanent /   http://www.exampleWithoutHttps.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've come across this same issue. It is BAD to load a client's competitor's site just because they don't need SSL!

Comment: Ok like i feared not without a certificate but is there at least a way to block a request for 443 on the wrong domain ?

Comment: Why not get a proper certificate for domains that doesn't NEED https? And, are you sure your don't need https ? If you handle any personal data, you must protect it in most countries.

Comment: I was told to generate a self-signed certificate for each domain to prevent the redirects. However, this seems like a lousy approach when you have 100 unmanaged sites on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Configure any certificate for your `VirtualHost *:443` and you are done.

- Could be simply a self-signed certificate that you generate for yourself. Of course user will see a security warning. This is expected. Users specifically want https where s stands for **s**ecure. You don't hold a valid certificate for exampleWithoutHttps.com, hence you cannot give them **s**ecurity - it's correct they are warned about that.
- You could also get a valid cert for free from a couple of vendors.

Place the `VirtualHost *:443` of `ServerName  exampleWithoutHttps.com` before `VirtualHost *:443` of `ServerName  exampleWithHttps.com`. I mean place it textually as the first one in the Apache's configuration files. This ensures user will not see content from exampleWithHttps.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to forward the user from https://exampleWithoutHttps to http://exampleWithoutHttps on all domains whithout https.

In order to do the redirect, you need to first set up a https connection. You cannot set up a https connection with out a valid certificate etc.

So to answer the question, you can't do it. Well, not in a manner that would satisfy most people who have any concerns over security anyway.

Comment: He is not looking to DO a redirect, he is looking to PREVENT a redirect. Most servers load the first site with SSL when HTTPS is requested instead of serving the current domain with an invalid certificate.

Comment: Read the 3rd paragraph, it's the one I quoted he explicitly says what he wants to do and that's what I answered.

Comment: >> "Now the problem is that if I access https://exampleWithoutHttps I will come to the content of https://exampleWithHttps."

The OP is trying to come up with a solution within his question. Obviously, that solution doesn't work. There's no point in creating an "answer" quoting his incorrect answer and stating that it's not a correct answer.

Comment: What about paragraph 6 as well ? `Is there a way I could have a redirect without a ssl certificate ?` the answer to which is also contained in my answer.

Comment: if you think my answer is wrong then just down vote it - simples.